# Analytic function on D restriction to U is one-to-one,then it is one-to-one on D?

Tags: complex-analysis

> problem: let $f(z)$ be analytic function on $D=\{|z|＜1\}$. there is an annulus $U=\{r＜|z|＜1\}$ such that the restriction of $f(z)$ to $U$ is one-to-one. Show that $f(z)$ is one-to-one on $D$.

I don't know how to use the condition ''the restriction of $f(z)$ to $U$ is one-to-one''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $r <\rho <1$ and let $C$ the circle $|z|=\rho$ and $J=f(C)$ an analytic Jordan curve; if $w \notin J$ then (by the argument principle) the number of zeroes of $f(z)-w, |z| < \rho$ is given by the winding number $\chi(J,w)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_J\frac {d\xi}{\xi-w}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_C\frac {f'(\zeta)d \zeta}{f(\zeta)-w}$ and said number is $0$ if $w$ is exterior to $J$ and $\pm 1$ if $w$ is interior.

In particular we get that $f$ takes all values inside $J$ precisely once when $|z| < \rho$ and no values outside $J$; now $f$ is an open map so the previous fact implies that $f$ cannot take any value on $J$ when $|z| <\rho$ so indeed $f$ is $1-1$ on $|z| \le \rho$. Letting $\rho \to 1$ shows that $f$ is $1-1$ on $D$ so done!

(edit later to clarify as asked)

by definition, if $J$ is a (nice enough - eg rectifiable) closed curve, the winding number of $w \notin J$ is $\chi(J,w)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_J\frac {d\xi}{\xi-w}$. This is an integer and is continuous in $w \notin J$ so, in particular, is constant on the connected components of the complement of $J$ and by letting $|w| \to \infty$ it is clearly zero on the unbounded component (which is unique regardless whether $J$ is Jordan or has self-intersections); if now $J$ is Jordan (simple) there is only one bounded component called the inside of $J$ and it is easy to see that the result there is $\pm 1$ since the winding number is invariant to homotopy (as long as we keep the crucial condition that $w \notin J_t, J_t, 0 \le t \le 1$ being a homotopy) and one can deform $J$ to a circle still having $w$ inside and for the circle, the computation is straightforward (in our case as $J$ is analytic one can show it is actually $1$ not $-1$ but that is less important)

Comment: OK,thanks your answer,but i can't understand it.such as :number is $0$ if  $ω$is exterior to $J$ and $\pm 1$ if $ω$ is interior. I can't understand your the second paragraph.I haven't study winding number.

Comment: added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof without any Jordan Curve Theorem machinery.

The argument comes down to selecting arbitrary $r_0 \in (r,1)$ and showing that $f$ is injective on $B(0,r_0)$. Via compactness we have  $\vert f(z')\vert =\max_{\vert z\vert =r_0} \vert f(z)\vert =M$.  Note $f(z')=M\cdot \exp(i\theta)$ (for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$) and this holds for only one $z' \in B(0,1)$ -- uniqueness comes by Max Modulus theorem for $\vert z \vert \lt r_0$ and by injectivity for $r_0\leq \vert z\vert \lt 1$.

$g(z):= f(z)- f(z')$ then select some $r^* \in (r_0,1)$ and by the Argument Principle
$n\big(f\circ \gamma_{r^*}, f(z')\big) = n\big(g\circ \gamma_{r^*}, 0\big)= v_g(z')\cdot n\big(\gamma_{r^*},z'\big) = 1\cdot 1=1$
where $\gamma_k(t) = r_k \cdot \exp\big(2\pi i\cdot t\big)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Then $ n\big(f\circ \gamma_{r^*}, w\big)=n\big(f\circ \gamma_{r^*}, f(z')\big)=1$ for all $w\in [f\circ\gamma_{r_0}]$
since they are path connected by $f\circ\gamma_{r_0}$ in $\mathbb C$ and hence in $\mathbb C- [f\circ \gamma_{r^*}]$ because injectivity in the outer annulus implies a trivial intersection of the images of the curves-- i.e. $[f\circ \gamma_{r^*}]\cap [f\circ \gamma_{r_0}]=\big\{\big\}$.

$n\big(f\circ \gamma_{r^*}, w\big)=1\text{ with Argument Principle }\implies f\big(B(0,r_0)\big)\cap [f\circ \gamma_{r_0}]=\big\{\big\}$ *and since the choice of* $r_0$ *was arbitrary this also implies* $f\big(B(0,r^*)\big)\cap [f\circ \gamma_{r^*}]= \big\{\big\} =f\big(\overline B(0,r_0)\big)\cap [f\circ \gamma_{r^*}]$ where the right hand side follows since $f\big(\overline B(0,r_0)\big)\subseteq f\big(B(0,r^*)\big)$

Finally $n\big(f\circ \gamma_{r^*},f(z)\big)=1$ as well for all $z\in B(0,r_0)$ as $f\big((1-\tau)\cdot z +\tau\cdot z'\big)$ for $\tau \in [0,1]$ gives a path from $f(z)$ to $f(z')$ in $\mathbb C-[f\circ\gamma_{r^*}]$.  By the Argument Principle we conclude that $f$ is injective on $B(0,r_0)$.